# How do I store menu item in webelements in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please help me in this. I have menu bar. Pasting screen shot from inspect elements. How do I store all menu item and respective href.

Refer to screen capture. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3l9I.png)

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks for your comment, I am new with Selenium web driver so I don't know how I can get the code for above screen capture. So I am learning selenium. So thought if someone can guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following it will capture all links under headerclass:

```
//ul[@class="headerclass"]//a
```